# Adding date filter to a barchart constructed using dc.js

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a barchart with ordinal values on the x-axis. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHTt2/19/). I would like to add a date filter. For example, filtering by month or year. I was trying to parse the dates to turn them into date objects, but unsuccessfully. So far I was only able to draw the graph. Here is the snippet of the data:

```
lst=[{
      "ActivityDate" : "2014-07-01",
      "ID" : "00000ysFOSEA2",
      "Owner" : "Eli Cher",
      "count" : 1
    },{
      "ActivityDate" : "2014-07-01",
      "ID" : "00Q400CEAQ",
      "Owner" : "Karl Bloch",
      "count" : 4
    },{
      "ActivityDate" : "2014-07-01",
      "ID" : "00Q4000ZEAU",
      "Owner" : "John Ding",
      "count" : 1
    },{
      "ActivityDate" : "2014-07-01",
      "ID" : "00Q40000ZEAU",
      "Owner" : "John Sha",
      "count" : 1
    },{
      "ActivityDate" : "2014-07-01",
      "ID" : "00Q40000zTEAW",
      "Owner" : "Joe Doe",
      "count" : 2
    },
]
```

Ideally, I would like to have a button that after pushed filters data to be this month's data. Help appreciated.

Comment: You should create a dimension for this filtering need (by month or year) I dont see anything about dates on your jsfiddle

Comment: @dimirc Hey. Thanks a lot for answering all the questions. Actually, I figured that one out long ago. I will write an answer for this one. The dates are in the lst, but I dont use them as a dimension.